# Extends encrypted partition to new SSD

Tags: partitioning, lvm, luks, merge

I have added a 1TB disk to my ubuntu 22.04 install.

I have installed it using LVM+LUKS. `lsblk` gives this

```
...
nvme1n1               259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
nvme0n1               259:1    0 476,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:2    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:3    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:4    0 475,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 474,8G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

So I can see the new drive here, next to the existing SSD. I would like to add the new disk to the `/` mount-point so that it just becomes 'one-big-disk', and preferable automatically unlocked when I enter the passphrase on boot-time.

I think because of the LVM it should be doable, but the LVM seems to be created inside the crypt partition.

Can this be done? And how?

Comment: It is possible, but you will always need both drives to use root partition. Once you have LUKS on the new drive you have to create LVM PV (physical volume) on it with pvcreate. Then add this PV to your existing LVM VG (volume group) vgubuntu with vgextend. Finally resize your logical volume "root" with lvresize.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not really what I wanted, but it sorta works.

I added the disk (that I formatted LUKS/Ext4) to the /etc/crypttab so that it is unlocked as well at boot (same passphrase), and mounted it on a subdir in my `/home`